# demucs.api or demucs.pretrained aren't working

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pytorch, anaconda

I created my environment and installed several packages for CUDA 11.8.0 (including demucs, pytorch, torchaudio, ffmpeg...). I want to separate a track with demucs with a python code in spyder (i don't want to do it on the anaconda prompt) however I've tried several codes and they seem not be working. I get errors like:

- AttributeError: module 'demucs' has no attribute 'Separator' (1)
- ImportError: cannot import name 'load_pretrained' from 'demucs.pretrained'  (2)   (C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\Pytorch\Lib\site-packages\demucs\pretrained.py)
- ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'demucs.api' (3)
- ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'demucs.model'(4)

So through the errors I assume my demucs package isn't working correctly but I don't know why. I've done the following (I'Ve found this either in google or in chatgpt):

- Checked Library Versions
- Upgraded demucs and other packages
  -deinstalled and reinstalled it
  Can someone please help me to solve this? What am I doing worng or why is demucs not working correctly?

This are the different codes I tested according to their errors above:

(1)

```
   import demucs
   separator = demucs.Separator()
   model = demucs.load_pretrained('demucs')
   audio_sources = separator.separate('Zweite_Aufnahme_mit_Piano.wav')
   for source_name, source_audio in audio_sources.items():
       source_audio.to_file(source_name + '.wav')
```

(2)

```
   import torchaudio
   from demucs.pretrained import load_pretrained
   import soundfile as sf
   import os

   input_audio_file = 'Zweite_Aufnahme_mit_Piano.wav'
   output_directory = 'Separated_audios'

   model = load_pretrained('demucs_quantized')

   audio, _ = torchaudio.load(input_audio_file)

   sources = model(audio)

   os.makedirs(output_directory, exist_ok=True)

   for i, source in enumerate(sources):
       source_path = os.path.join(output_directory, f'source_{i}.wav')
       sf.write(source_path, source[0].numpy(), 44100)

   print("Source separation complete. Separated sources saved in the output directory.")
```

(3)

```
   from pydub import AudioSegment
   import IPython
   import numpy as np
   import demucs.api
   import pathlib
   import torch

   audiosegment = AudioSegment.from_mp3("Zweite_Aufnahme_mit_Piano.wav")
   arr = audiosegment.get_array_of_samples()
   sr = audiosegment.frame_rate
   ch = audiosegment.channels
   aac = np.array(arr, dtype=np.float32).reshape((-1, ch))
   aac = aac[30*sr:40*sr,:]
   IPython.display.Audio(aac[:, 0], rate=sr)

   separator = demucs.api.Separator()
   model = separator.load_model()
   input = torch.from_numpy(aac.reshape((ch, -1)))
   separator.add_track("born", input)
   separated = separator.separate_loaded_audio()
   for (file, stems) in separated:
       for stem, waveform in stems.items():
         print(stem)
         print(waveform.shape)
         aac_again = waveform.numpy().reshape((-1, ch))
         IPython.display.display(IPython.display.Audio(aac_again[:,0], rate=sr))
```

(4)

```
   import torchaudio
   from demucs.model import load_pretrained

   audio, sample_rate = torchaudio.load('Zweite_Aufnahme_mit_Piano.wav')
   model = load_pretrained('demucs')
   separated_sources = model(audio)
   torchaudio.save('vocals.wav', separated_sources['vocals'], sample_rate)
   torchaudio.save('accompaniment.wav', separated_sources['accompaniment'], sample_rate)
   torchaudio.save('drums.wav', separated_sources['drums'], sample_rate)
   torchaudio.save('bass.wav', separated_sources['bass'], sample_rate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding demucs to your system variables but I don't think it will work..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35380842)